# how to locate fxml from another package?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have created a simple `JavaFX` application.

[image]

It has two packages the main class is `JFXTest2.java`  is in `good` package and the fxml and it's controller are in `JFXTest2` package.

now the problem is that i can not load the fxml in the main class. I tried loading the
fxml like this:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("jfxtest2.Screen.fxml"));
```

and

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("jfxtest2/Screen.fxml"));
```

and also

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(new URL("/jfxtest2/Screen.fxml"));
```

but none of them worked.So how should i load the fxml from JFXTest2 package in the the JFXTest2 class which is the `main` class or `application class`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/jfxtest2/Screen.fxml"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/jfxtest2/Screen.fxml")
```

Answer (score -2):

For me nothing worked besides this:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("..//jfxtest2//Screen.fxml"));
```